# Practical interpretation of Precision-Recall AUC

Tags: machine-learning, classification, unbalanced-classes, auc, precision-recall

I have a classifier with an AUC (PR) of 0.06 which I will use for a practical interpretation.

My test set consists of three months of data with a total of 2,200,000 observations of which 0.03 are labelled as the positive class (1).

Can I then use the following calculation: (2,200,000*0.03/90)*0.06 = 44, where 90 represents the three months.

From the above, can I then say that my classifier correctly classifies 44 true positive observations per day? Or should/could I interpret the AUC (PR) of 0.06 in another practical way?

Answer (score 1):

When the "positive class" is rare, attempting to make all-or-nothing classifications will usually be misleading and not very informative.  It is far better to predict *tendencies* in such cases, and measures such as sensitivity, specificity, proportion "correctly" "classified", precision, and recall are improper accuracy scores that when optimized will result in the wrong features being selected and the wrong weights being given to them.  This can most easily be seen by your case in which "classifying" every observation as negative will result in an accuracy of 0.97.  These issues are detailed [here](http://www.fharrell.com/tags/classification).

Estimation of tendencies by estimating the probability of positive will result in optimum decisions, which in some cases will be "no decision" when there are close calls (intermediate probabilities).  Class calls are completely lost when using classification rather than prediction.